# How do I use UserDocument/UserModel in jest Testcases using NestJs

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, jestjs, nestjs

I am trying to add actual value to the database using nestjs with jest test cases.

The main purpose of test cases is to actually check the database values written and retrived from the database. So I'm not mocking any `save` or `find` method as I want to make the actual connection to the database and retrive the records from there. So without mocking the `save()` and `find()` methods I'm not able get the test cases running. The compilation fails without it.

I am stuck with `users.service.spec.ts` file in which I want to use `UserDocument` and it's methods `create()`,`findAll()`.

```
//user.entity.ts

import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

export type UserDocument = User & Document;

@Schema()
export class User {
    
  @Prop({ unique: true })
  username: string;

  @Prop()
  age: number;

  @Prop()
  password: string;
}

export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);
```

```
// User.module.ts

import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose'
import { User, UserSchema } from './schemas/user.schema'
import { UsersController } from './users.controller';

@Module({
  imports: [MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: User.name, schema: UserSchema }])],
  controllers: [UsersController],
  providers: [UsersService],
  exports: [UsersService]
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

```
// users.controller.ts

import { Controller, Get, Post, Body, Patch, Param, Delete,UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';
import { CreateUserDto } from './dto/create-user.dto';
import { UpdateUserDto } from './dto/update-user.dto';


@Controller('users')
export class UsersController {
  constructor(private readonly usersService: UsersService) {}

  @Post()
  create(@Body() createUserDto: CreateUserDto) {
    return this.usersService.create(createUserDto);
  }

  @Get()
  findAll() {
    return this.usersService.findAll();
  }

}
```

```
//users.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CreateUserDto } from './dto/create-user.dto';
import { UpdateUserDto } from './dto/update-user.dto';
import { User, UserDocument } from './schemas/user.schema';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
   constructor(@InjectModel(User.name) private userModel: Model<UserDocument>) {}

  async create(createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<User> {
   const createdUser = new this.userModel(createUserDto);
    return await createdUser.save();
  }

  async findAll(): Promise<User[]> {
    return await this.userModel.find().exec();
  }

}
```

```
//users.service.spec.ts

import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing'
import { UsersService } from './users.service'
import { AppConfigModule } from '../config/app-config.module'
import { AppConfigService } from '../config/app-config.service'
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config'
import { MongooseModule, getModelToken } from '@nestjs/mongoose'
import { PaginationQuery } from 'src/helpers/pagination/pagination-query.dto'
import { User, UserSchema, UserDocument } from './entities/user.entity'

describe('UsersService', () => {
  let service: UsersService
  let userDocument: UserDocument

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
          isGlobal: true,
          cache: true
        }),
        MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
          imports: [AppConfigModule],
          inject: [AppConfigService],
          useFactory: (config: AppConfigService) => ({
            uri: `mongodb://${config.TESTDATABASE_HOST}:${config.TESTDATABSE_PORT}`,
            dbName: config.TESTDATABASE_NAME
          })
        })
      ],
      providers: [
        UsersService,
        {
          provide: getModelToken(User.name),
          useValue: UserDocument         // <----------- Not able to understand what will go here
        }
      ]
    }).compile()

    service = module.get<UsersService>(UsersService)
    userDocument = module.get<UserDocument>(UserDocument) // <---- As this is type here not accepting value
  })

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined()
  })

  it('create test data', async () => {
    expect(
      await service.create({
        name: 'demouser',
        email: 'demo@gmail.com',
        password: 'demo@123',
        role: 'user'
      })
    ).toEqual({
      statusCode: 201,
      message: 'User created successfully',
      data: {
        isActive: true,
        role: 'user',
        password:
          '$2b$10$VjwR0Wjf6vTaRjQlsizB5OLY04NJOcRyC/pPLbTPTQnWTDIrBU.Sq',
        email: 'demo@gmail.com',
        name: 'demouser',
        _id: expect.any(Number)
      }
    })
  })


})
```

As I've highlighted in the spec file, `UserDocument` is the type defined in the `users.entity.ts` file, the value UserDocument is not accepted in the `userDocument = module.get<UserDocument>(UserDocument)` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved my Problem Error.

Adding this import, it resolved my error.

`MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: User.name, schema: UserSchema }])`

I can add the Actual value to the database

```
//users.service.spec.ts
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing'
import { UsersService } from './users.service'
import { AppConfigModule } from '../config/app-config.module'
import { AppConfigService } from '../config/app-config.service'
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config'
import { MongooseModule, getModelToken } from '@nestjs/mongoose'
import { User, UserSchema } from './entities/user.entity'
import { isValidObjectId } from 'mongoose'
import { HttpException } from '@nestjs/common'

const testUser = {
  name: 'demouser',
  email: 'demo@gmail.com',
  password: 'demo@123',
  role: 'user'
}
describe('UsersService', () => {
  let service: UsersService

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
          isGlobal: true,
          cache: true
        }),
        MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
          imports: [AppConfigModule],
          inject: [AppConfigService],
          useFactory: (config: AppConfigService) => ({
            uri: `mongodb://${config.TESTDATABASE_HOST}:${config.TESTDATABSE_PORT}`,
            dbName: config.TESTDATABASE_NAME
          })
        }),
        MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: User.name, schema: UserSchema }])//-------import model here
      ],
      providers: [UsersService]
    }).compile()

    service = module.get<UsersService>(UsersService)
  })

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined()
  })
  
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`userDocument = module.get<UserDocument>(UserDocument)` must be
`userDocument = module.get<UserDocument>(getModelToken(User.name))`
since you're trying to get the stub that you have defined for `getModelToken(User.name)` provider

In `useValue: UserDocument` you must use some stub/mock object like this one: https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs/blob/6c77b2a5001a48673c77c9659d985a083354579f/apps/sequelize-sample/src/cats/cats.service.spec.ts#L17-L20 since you're trying to not use the real model.

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to use the real model. As I want to add the data to a real database. Is there any way for that?